# How can I get the Microsoft Expressions 4 Codec to work on XP SP3?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, codec, screen-recorder, microsoft-expression

The codec allows you to preview the recording you just took.  The recorder itself and the encoder both seem to work just fine, but when I try to preview a recording it says it can't find the codec.  The codec is definitely there and in the same directory.
[image: The error]

[image: The codec in the same directory as everything else]

**EDIT**: I have tried reinstalling. It did not fix the problem. I am having the same problem on 2 other XP machines as well

**EDIT**: I tried re-registering the codec per Aaron's suggestion.  The registration succeeded, but I still get the same error when I attempt to preview a recording

**EDIT**: After doing some more research, I was able to find a version of MS Expression 4 Encoder "without codecs." Surprisingly, this version works perfectly fine on Windows 7 with no errors, but the exact same installation produces the same errors I have already described when I try to preview recordings in Windows XP.  How do I get the program to work as well on XP as it does on 7?

Comment: What software are you using to preview the video? Cannot tell if it is Expression or something else like VLC.

Comment: It is Expression's previewer.  I added pics

Comment: What happens when you reinstall Expression? It may relink/register the DLL.

Comment: You might also try re-registering the codec DLL manually in Command Prompt, via the `regsvr32` command; the actual invocation might be something like `regsvr32 c:\path\to\codec.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the Codec and re-installing it.
Get it from this link: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10732